# Create dynamic .aspx pages in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following code creates file.aspx and file.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fielName = Server.MapPath("~/file.aspx");        
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fielName);        
    tw.WriteLine(@"<%@ Page Language=""C#"" AutoEventWireup=""true""  CodeFile=""file.aspx.cs"" Inherits=""file"" %>
                   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"">
                    <html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
                    <head runat=""server"">
                        <title></title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <form id=""form1"" runat=""server"">
                        <div>

                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </body>
                    </html>
                    ");        
    tw.Close();
    tw = new StreamWriter(fielName + ".cs");

    tw.WriteLine(@"using System;
                    using System.Collections.Generic;
                    using System.Linq;
                    using System.Web;
                    using System.Web.UI;
                    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
                    using System.IO;

                    public partial class file : System.Web.UI.Page
                    {
                        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                        {
                           Response.Write(""new File "");

                        }
                    }
                    ");       
    tw.Close();
}
```

I want to make the page name written in my Textbox.

I have tried putting textbox in html source of above code, but I'm getting an error.

```
CodeFile="""+TextBox1.Text+""" Inherits="""+TextBox1.Text+"""
```

Comment: What you are doing is not a good practice instead use an html editor and save your contect in database and when you need your content load your page with page id .let me know if you need further help.
Second there will be security issue on online server

Comment: How will your pages be dynamic if you just create a new aspx page (and codebehind) on the server folder structure? Depending on your deployment you will need to compile those pages. I'm pretty sure that aspx pages are already "dynamic" enough to fit your purposes, what ever it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Depends on the framework you are working with. 4.0 definitely requires compiling. The classes are actually loaded from a compiled assembly in the bin folder. I can't remember if you can even make the old web projects like this in 4.0. Maybe. I know I used to years ago have a web project on 2.0 that dynamically compiled the cs files.

Comment: My first question is "Why?" What overall goal are you trying to achieve by coding your aspx's like this?

Comment: @valverij  I required

Answer (score 1):

You would be much farther ahead to work the way ASP.NET "thinks" about the page. I once worked on a very large, dynamic questionnaire. All of the controls were generated dynamically along with validations and everything else. At it's core, the way we did it was:

- place a panel on the page
- add controls to the panel

the code very roughly would look something like this:

```
        var btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "theId";
        btn.Text = "hi";
        pnlDynamic.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Because you're dealing with dynamic controls, you might also want to make sure that you understand the page life-cycle...: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your web project is declared as a [web site rather than a web application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx).

A web site is willing to dynamically compile each page on demand, unlike a web application, so something like this is in principle doable.  If you really want to do it.